# Where can I get CSS and JavaScript navigation menus and controls?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to implement a very professional looking navigation menu with multiple drop down elements and the ability to nest sub-menus etc.

Its for a business app. Are there any free menu controls that can be used?

Maybe with CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, simple, pure CSS (but semantic and decent HTML code) menu controls aren't too hard to make from scratch. Take something like [this](http://jsbin.com/odipeb/2/edit#preview) and tweak the colors and fonts to suit the website.

http://jsbin.com/odipeb/2/edit#html,live

Comment: @Pete2k do you mean the link is broken, or that the menu at the link doesn't work? try [this](http://jsbin.com/odipeb/2/edit#html,live)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cssplay.co.uk and the sites it links too have the best ones I've seen by far :)

Comment: Nice. He's got a couple dozen variations there. All CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I had to look around quite a lot when teaching myself this stuff, and that site worked wonders :)